# How did they come up with the units of flow supplied by $b, c$, and $d$?

Tags: network, network-flow

I am a bit confused on how the numbers $60, 40$, and $40$ came about as the flow $b, c$, and $d$ supply respectively. This example is under "Flow Networks with Supplies and Demands." I understand they added vertex a to show that multiple sources can be combined into one, but what made them choose those specific values?

Example:
"Consider the network of solid edges in Figure 4.4 with supplies and demands. Vertex
$b$ can supply up to $60$ units of flow, and vertices $c$ and $d$ can each supply $40$ units.
Vertices $h, i$, and $j$ have flow demands of $50, 40$, and $40$ units, respectively."

[image: Figure 4.4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper bounds on the arcs out of the source node $a$ are the supplies of nodes $b$, $c$, and $d$.
The upper bounds on the arcs into the sink node $z$ are the demands of nodes $h$, $i$, and $j$.

Comment: But why? Consider a cut (X, Y) where X = {b, c, d} and Y = {e, f, g}. The total capacity of that cut is 150. How come the total output of the vertex a is only 140, then?

Comment: A cut is usually defined to be a partition of the nodes.  So for a given $X \subset N$, you should take $Y=N \setminus X$.  Yes, the capacity of that cut is 150, but a better upper bound on the maximum flow is the sum of supplies 140, and an even better upper bound is the sum of demands 130.  The latter two values (140 and 130) arise as cut capacities after you introduce source $a$ and sink $z$.

Comment: I see. I was misunderstanding the example. So the supply and demands of the vertices are GIVEN. To reconfirm, since the maximum flow of the three possibilities (sum of the demands, sum of the supplies, and maximum flow capacity of cut, which oddly enough means the minimum value) is 130, then 130 is the flow value of the network. Correct?

Comment: You have found an upper bound of 130 from a cut.  To establish a lower bound of 130, you need to also find a corresponding flow.